# Music is not getting stop when scene reload in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a toggle button to play and stop music and I am using playerPrefs to save the state. Toggle button is playing or stopping the music but when I reload the scene It gets messed up. Music keeps playing even if the toggle button is on(Means set the music off).

For the player Prefs. I am using Player prefs Manager script:

```
public static void SetMusicOnOFF(int value)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Music, value);      
}

public static int GetMusicOnOff()
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(Music, 5);
}
```

For the toggle button I am using:

```
class MusicToggleButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    Toggle t;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        t = GetComponent<Toggle>();

        if (PlayerPrefsManager.GetMusicOnOff() == 1)
        { //ERROR CALLING THE METHOD TO CHANGE MUSIC TO ON
            t.isOn = true;
        }          
    }
```

When the toggle button is pressed I am calling StartStopMusicPlayer method:

```
class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool stopPlayer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake ()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefsManager.GetMusicOnOff() == 2)
        {  
            audioSource.Play();
            audioSource.playOnAwake = true;
            audioSource.loop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
    }

    public void StartStopMusicPlayer()
    {
        stopPlayer = !stopPlayer;
        if (stopPlayer)
        {
            PlayerPrefsManager.SetMusicOnOFF(1);
            audioSource.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefsManager.SetMusicOnOFF(2);
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    } 
}
```

Music Player Class is not destroying on reload. But the MusicToggleButton class is destroyed on reload.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the audio set to play on awake. I would say don't play on awake but set it to play if you need to.

Comment: Can you check the default value of the toggle button when the scene is loaded? Perhaps you can ensure the value of the toggle button in `MusicToggleButton` by adding `else { t.isOn = false;  }`

Comment: Thank you guys for your answer. Yes thomas I am not setting it on awake. I think I have found where is the problem. When I am reloading the scene. In the awake I am changing t.isOn=true. That is calling that method which changes the music from off to on. Because when scene loads toggle state is off and inside awake i am changing it to on. That messing things up. I think so. Now what should I do?

Comment: **I have searched on google. This is the problem with toggle. I should change the toggle button to a normal button. Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Calling PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Music, value) is not enough. You should call PlayerPrefs.Save() after that. Or your changes will not take effect after restart.

```
public static void SetMusicOnOFF(int value)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Music, value);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I was not aware of this. you are saying each time I am setting player pref value. I should write PlayerPrefs.Save(); ?

Comment: Although Unity saves preferences automatically in OnApplicationQuit there is still cases when your PlayerPrefs won't save. So yes you should. For more details follow https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html

Comment: Thank you so much Sat for this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was so simple. If anyone want to know. Just change the toggle button with normal button. and Inside the MusicToggleButton class.

```
public class MusicToggleButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image offOnImage;
    public bool changeValue;
    public Color TargetColor;
    public Color originalColor;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        changeValue = !(PlayerPrefsManager.GetMusicOnOff() == 1);
        if (PlayerPrefsManager.GetMusicOnOff() == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("stop Music");
            offOnImage.color = TargetColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Playing Music");
            offOnImage.color = originalColor;
        }
    }

    public void musicButtonClick()
    {
        changeValue = !changeValue;
        if (changeValue)
        {
            //Debug.Log("changing to target color");
            //offOnImage.CrossFadeColor(TargetColor, 0.5f, false, false);
            offOnImage.color = originalColor;
            Debug.Log("Playing");
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("changing to original color");
            //offOnImage.CrossFadeColor(Color.white, 0.5f, false, false);
            Debug.Log("pause");
            offOnImage.color = TargetColor;
        }
    }
}
```

This will do Play and pause music. Act like a toggle button.